# How to do Rollback with Transactional Annotation

Tags: java, spring, jdbctemplate

I am trying to do Transactional Rollback in my methods. Intentionally i am making the insert fails to find out . But i don't see its getting rolled back . Please help what i am missing.

```
@Service
public class ModesService implements IModesService{

ChargeRuleDao chargeRuleDao;

public ModesService(ChargeRuleDao chargeRuleDao){
    this.chargeRuleDao = chargeRuleDao;
}

@Override
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public void process(ChargeRule chargeRule){
    chargeRuleDao.deleteShippingChargeAttr(shippingChargeRuleID);
    chargeRuleDao.deleteShippingCharge(shippingChargeRuleID);
    chargeRuleDao.deleteShippingChargeDest(shippingChargeRuleID);

    //Delete
    chargeRuleDao.insertShipChargeFeedRule(chargeRule);
        
}
```

In DAOImpl class i have methods like below for all deletions and insertion.

```
@Override
public int deleteShippingChargeAttr(String test) {
    MapSqlParameterSource params = new MapSqlParameterSource();
    params.addValue("ABC" "ABC", Types.VARCHAR);
    return jdbcTemplate.update(DELETE_QUERY, params);

}
```

Comment: How are you making it fail?

Comment: throw new RuntimeException();

Comment: Enable @Transaction log, it will help you to debug. `logging.level.org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate=debug`

Comment: Consider database limitation too. Example MySQL - MyISAM engine doesn't support transactions. You can't rollback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try `@Transactional(rollbackFor = XYZException.class)`.
XYZException should be an exception which should wrap all the exceptions/exception for which you want to rollback the transaction.

Comment: unfortunately this is not working . i am throwing a runtime exception in my insertmethod 
 throw new RuntimeException();
And catching it in @Transactional . But no luck .but will it roll back already committed delete method ?

Comment: Above one did work for me.. It would have been better to get to see the code... Did you try kind of following `@Transactional(rollbackFor = XYZException.class)
 public void methodAbcd(......)
   throws XYZException {
  .
  .
  .
 }`

Answer (score 1):

Rollback occurs by default for every unchecked exception. That means you need to throw some type unchecked exception, like for example

```
throw new NullPointerException();
```

in your insertShipChargeFeedRule(chargeRule);

more about @Transactional here https://javamondays.com/spring-transactions-explained/

Comment: I tried as you suggested but no luck , not sure what i am missing

Comment: Can you show how exactly are you doing it? essentially, if you were to make a try { throw new NullPointerException(); } catch (NullPointerException e) {} instead of a //Delete comment, it should rollback the transaction. Also your insert method should, as long as it is marked as @Transactional (so that it supports the current transaction which it does by default) and it throws an exception - which you should also catch for your program to keep running.